# How to change font/color on MFC dialog for Windows Mobile?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, mfc

Does anyone know how to set font and color on a static text and other controls of MFC dialog for Windows Mobile?

Where can I get the list of supported fonts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colors are changed via [SetBkColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920825.aspx) and [SetTextColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911461.aspx).

[Here is an example](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2007/06/22/EnumeratingAndAddingFontsInWindowsCE.aspx) of enumerating fonts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the control, but take a look at the Windows messages starting with WM_CTLCOLOR (e.g., WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC). For the fonts, use EnumFontFamilies.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Fonts-in-Windows-Mobile-2003-Second-Edition